# How to pass input parameters to java program in php

Tags: java, php, shell, command-line, compiler-construction

to be specific, i'm creating a website that will allow user to Write and Execute java program online.

I've write code that compiles and execute java program online using PHP.
Here is the code :

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>php java demo</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    exec("jdk\\bin\\javac demo.java 2>&1", $output);
    print_r($output);

    exec("jdk\\bin\\java -Xmx512M -Xms64M demo 2>&1" , $output1);

    print_r($output1);
?>
</body>
```

this works perfect.
but when I've to give input to program using BufferedReader or other schemes, this method fails.

```
Enter a number                                                                     Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at demo.main(demo.java:7)
```

for example a am trying to make that STDIN input box at the bottom of http://www.compileonline.com/compile_java_online.php

please help me.

Comment: Take that off line now.  It is open to executable injection with full file system access.

Answer (score 0):

It worked fine when i tried to use BufferedReader in my program.

Flosculus is right. I was able create new directory in the server you are hosting, browse your drives.... etc etc.